# IIS 7.5 - Change Application Pool Start Mode to Always Running

Tags: iis-7.5, machine.config

I have IIS 7.5 and I have installed the Application Initialization Module for it. Now, I am trying to change the StartMode of an application pool, but do not see the StartMode option in the IIS Manager. I have looked under Basic and Advanced Settings. I am thinking that the next place to edit this value would be in the Machine.Config. So, I have found that file, but I am unsure where the update would be placed in there. I believe it should be set to AlwaysRunning.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the `Configuration Editor` under the `Management` section of the `IIS manager`.

**EDIT**: `startMode` is in section `system.applicationHost/applicationPools` under `applicationPoolDefaults`. It can also be configured on a per-item basis in `Application Pools` - `Advanced Settings`.

Comment: The last sentence of your edit is not correct according to [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677285(v=azure.10).aspx). _"The autoStart attribute and startMode attributes of an application pool are different. The startMode attribute is the one that the auto-start feature of Windows Server AppFabric uses. The Start application pool immediately setting in the Edit Application Pool dialog box or Start Automatically setting on the Advanced Settings dialog box of an application pool configures the autoStart attribute, not the startMode attribute."_

Answer (score 4):

In this entry http://developers.de/blogs/damir_dobric/archive/2009/10/11/iis-7-5-and-always-running-web-applications.aspx i found the answer.

To setup the pool set the attribute startMode to AlwaysRunning of the IIS config file C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config:

```
<applicationPools> 
    <add name="MyAppWorkerProcess" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning" /> 
</applicationPools>
```

And you need implements others things to reach that your App always running

Answer (score 0):

If you like to have a **UI**, look at this link 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amol/2013/01/25/application-initialization-ui-for-iis-7-5/
and download the "ApplicationInitializationInstaller_x64.zip".
after install you find a new icon on the iis-manager (on the server-element).